# Angular js : how to use loop in directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am creating directive for form controls, there is fix json with all possible from question and there options.

Html

```
<text-control-dir data="que.QuestionData" default="{{[_attributename]}}"></text-control-dir>
```

controlDirective.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
            .module("autoQuote")
            .directive('textControlDir', [textControlDir])
            .directive('selectControlDir', [selectControlDir])
            .directive('radioControlDir', [radioControlDir])
            .directive('hiddenControlDir', [hiddenControlDir]);

    function textControlDir()
    {
        return {
            transclude: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: { 
                data: '=data'
            },
            template: "<div ng-transclude></div><label>{{data._text}} </label><input type='text' name='{{data._attributeName}}' id='{{data._attributeName}}' value='' >"
            ,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs)
            {
                //console.log(scope.data);
            }
        };
    }

    function selectControlDir()
    {
        return {
            transclude: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: { 
                data: '=data',
                default: '=default'
            },
            template: ""
            ,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs)
            {
                consoile.log('link data');
                console.log(scope.default);
            }
        };
    }

    function radioControlDir()
    {
        console.log('here in radio directive');
        return {
            transclude: true,
            template: "<h1>Made by a radio directive!</h1>"
        };
    }

    function hiddenControlDir()
    {
        return {
            transclude: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: { 
                data: '=data'
            },
            template: "<div ng-transclude></div><label>{{data._text}} </label><input type='hidden' name='{{data._attributeName}}' id='{{data._attributeName}}' value='' >"
            ,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs)
            {
                //console.log(scope.data);
            }
        };
    }

}());
```

I am not getting how to loop to create select options.

Comment: I presume you've taken a look at http://angular-formly.com/#/? Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your template's `ng-repeat` you have to use `in` instead of `as` here:

```
template: "<div ng-transclude></div><label>{{data._text}} </label><select type='text' name='{{data._attributeName}}' id='{{data._attributeName}}' >\n\
<option ng-repeat='ans in data.QuestionData._answerOptions'>{{ans._promptText}}</option></select>",
```

[Your updated plnkr.](http://plnkr.co/edit/t2vENRDx9TR5kTiTVjbP?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you. you can see in result first four select control do not have any option. options for these will come through  a call and will get updated on change. how to set here ajax call methods.

Comment: @Greatym.com That is too broad to answer actually. It would be better to post a new question about it. Although that is perfectly doable.

Comment: please see here fore new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456404/angular-js-how-to-make-make-ajax-call-for-directives-to-create-options/38456580?noredirect=1#comment64317527_38456580

Comment: @Greatym.com just added an answer check that.

Comment: Thanks Jai, How can we set selected option in ng-repeat

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/bc7cii5gkyNhhT4NS3uv?p=preview

It's better to use `ngOptions` directive because it's much faster!

Avoid options with label 'Please Select' - look at my example.

Comment: its working fine now. one more thing for here how to make ajax call on option changes

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/cQ1a8iFGRbx0kkR6x0JW?p=preview (look at selectControlDir function)  or you could watch specific model in you controller and make ajax calls

Comment: how to set selected value in ngOptions using link function