# Angular js : How to make make ajax call for directives to create options

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

I created directives for form controls. 
There are some controls those will have options from ajax[API] call.

I am stuck here how to make ajax call over directives.

```
    function selectControlDir()
    {
        return {
            transclude: true,
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                data: '=data'
            },
            template: "<div ng-transclude></div><label>{{data._text}} </label><select type='text' name='{{data._attributeName}}' id='{{data._attributeName}}' >\n\
<option ng-repeat='ans in data._answerOptions'>{{ans._promptText}}</option></select>"
            ,
            link: function (scope, element, attrs)
            {
                //console.log("scope.data.QuestionData", scope.data.QuestionData);
            }
        };
    }
```

Plunker for complete code 
http://plnkr.co/edit/Op1QDwUBECAosPUC7r3N?p=preview

Here I want to make api call for Year (on page load).
on year change update options of Make.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do for this is better to have a `ng-change` event directive on the `year` element and in the controller you can use to have an array which holds all the make happened in that year:

```
var app = angular.module('yourApp', []);

app.controller('yourController', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.o = {
      makes: [{make:'Make1'}, {make:'Make2'}], // <---just for demo
      getMake: function(year) {
        $http.post(url, {
            year: year  // <----pass the year to backend as year like : { year:1990 }
          })
          .then(function success(response) {
              $scope.o.makes = response.data; // <---put actual data here
            },
            function error(e) {
              console.error(e);
            });
      }
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<div ng-app='yourApp' ng-controller='yourController'>
  <select ng-model='year' ng-change='o.getMake(year)'>
    <option>1990</option>
    <option>1991</option>
  </select>
    <select ng-model='make' ng-options='make as make.make for make in o.makes track by make.make'>
    <option>Make...</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get the options by angular service. The angular service will send the AJAX call and return the result (and even some default data in case of failure).

How to do it? Here is an example:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
//Service
app.factory('myService', function(){
  function getOption() {
      return 'getOption';
  }
  return {
      getOption: getOption
  }
});

app.directive('myDirective', ['myService',function(myService){
  return {
    template: '<h1>{{name}}</h1>'
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.name = myService.getOption();
    }
  }
}]);
```

Comment: In plunker I created common directive for all select type querstion. here I want to introduce ajax call for year(onload) and model(on year change). How to do here?

Answer (score 0):

Use can use $http to make ajax call. You need to inject it to use it. Better solution is to move the service calls to factory/service.

```
function selectControlDir($http)
{
    return {
        transclude: true,
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            data: '=data'
        },
        template: "<div ng-transclude></div><label>{{data._text}} </label

> ><select type='text' name='{{data._attributeName}}' id='{{data._attributeName}}' >\n\ <option ng-repeat='ans in
> data._answerOptions'>{{ans._promptText}}</option></select>"

        ,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs)
        {
            // $http.post(url, options); => make your call here    
            //console.log("scope.data.QuestionData", scope.data.QuestionData);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: $http.post or $http.get => make your call here    "this is helpful"  but how to set options.

Comment: @pandudas : options means some parameters?

Comment: added api.php this will return a jason. option means <select><option value=""><option> these options are in directive template that should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create a *service* or a *factory* and inject it into your *directive*.

```
app.service("serviceName", ["$http", function($http) {
  return {
    getData: function(configObject) {
      // $http.get(..., post... etc
    }
  }
}]);
```

You can use it in your *link* or in *controller* statement.

```
selectControlDir(serviceName) {
  return{
    ...
    link: function() {
      selectControlDir.getData({ url: ..., getParam1: 123})
    }
    ... or ...
    controller: function() {
      selectControlDir.getData({ url: ..., getParam1: 123})
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I got that selectControlDir.getData({ url: ..., getParam1: 123}) will return some data but how to use that to set select options <option>....

Comment: @pandudas don't use in select ng-repeat on options, better use ng-options in select > https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions then you can set the value with $scope.modelName